# How to calculate or get surface area of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, measurement

How do I get the surface area of a mesh? Preferably no python involved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Enable the '3D Print Toolbox' addon.

[image]

**2.79**

2. Open the '3D Printing' tab in *3D view > Tool shelf*.
3. Under statistics, press the **Area** button. (there's also option for volume and other checks for geometry).

[image]

**2.8+**

The Addons shelf has been moved on the right of the screen. Press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D Viewport or click the arrow in the top right of the area to expand it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a Python solution to calculating the total surface area in case someone arrives to this thread searching for a python alternative. Make sure you [`Apply`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) the scale first.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data

total_area = 0
for p in mesh.polygons:
    total_area += p.area

print("Total Surface Area:", total_area)
```

Here's a `bmesh` approach:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

total_area = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)

print("Total Surface Area:", total_area)
bm.free()
```