# Surface area of an object

Tags: modeling

How do I go about getting the surface area of an object in cm^2 in blender ?
Is there a tab I can find it or will it require a script?. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Just after posting my answer below I realized there is an identical question and answer that can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13974/get-surface-area-of-a-mesh. If you have any questions about where to find things he included some pictures as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon called the *3D Print Toolbox* which is included in Blender that has this function. It can be found in the addons list in the User Preferences. Once you have the addon enabled, the new options will be in a new tab in the toolbar. At the top there is an area button that will calculate the surface area. I'm assuming your using centimeters as your units. If not, go to the scene tab, and in the *Units* panel switch the preset to centimeters. You may have to adjust the scale based on whatever you were working on. By default, centimeters are 100 times smaller than the default Blender units.

**EDIT:** IF you are working with different units already and don't want to mess things up you will have to do the conversion manually from whatever unit you are in, as the output units are always in whatever units the scene is using. There is probably a way to get around this by modifying the addon if you are so inclined though.

Comment: Thanks alot. I how do you suppose I go about this mod. I'm not good at the programming aspect of blender

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with modifying the addon. Just keep a calculator handy and find the conversion factor from whatever units you are working in to square cm. If possible, I would just switch your scene units to cm, then scale everything back to the size you had before.

Comment: Not what you want but worth saying that if you want the area of a face then enable the Face Area option in the Overlays. As @Brenticus says use something like https://www.metric-conversions.org/area-conversion.htm then you can keep your default units of measure